# there is no default constructor available in Conferenceable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-event

I'm a beginner for android. I want to develop an app for the detection of conference call. so in this line, I faced `there is no default constructor available android.telecom.Conferenceable`.

```
 import android.telecom.Conferenceable;
 import android.telecom.Connection;

 public abstract class Conference extends Conferenceable {
    @Override
```

Comment: It is good practice on stackoverflow to post the relevant lines of your code, and the relevant parts of your stack trace. I'm sure you need a no-argument constructor which you don't have, but I don't know because you don't show the code.

Comment: @f1sh has mentioned correctly the reason to the problem

Comment: I know they have. I'm trying to educate the person asking the question, to no avail, I see.